# New Window Appears on Toolbar but GUI Doesn't Appear

Tags: unity, gui, ros

Getting an issue where the GUI does not show up properly. For a few buttons on this program instead of opening the proper new window, I get a 'blank' or ' invisible' one. After clicking 'export' the new window [appears on the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZFL.jpg) but the preview is blank (same for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) .

My active window **does** switch to this new one which takes up the whole screen. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't provide options to re-scale it. It could be a bug in this program (rviz), but I'm not sure.

If it makes any difference, I'm using a virtual machine.

Comment: If this behavior only exists using one application and especially if it only pertains to specific tasks in a single application, it's probably a bug in the application. You should file a bug report with the developer of that app

Answer (score 0):

If it makes a difference, it *was* an issue with using the application in a virtual machine. I tested it on a real installation and the windows appeared properly.